# Using Python's in-built methods for string formatting

Tags: python, string

I am trying to print a dictionary values

```
sales_record = {
'price': 3.24,
'num_items': 4,
'person': 'xyz'}

sales_statement = 'sales_record['person'] got sales_record['num_items'] item(s) at a cost of sales_record['price']each for a total of sales_record['price']*sales_record['num_items']'

print(sales_statement)
```

But this is simply giving me error

```
 File "<ipython-input-48-9c532ca6dcd1>", line 6
    sales_statement = 'sales_record['person'] got sales_record['num_items'] item(s) at a cost of sales_record['price']each for a total of sales_record['price']*sales_record['num_items']'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format your string. This will work for new and older versions of Python:

```
sales_statement = "{} got {} item(s) at a cost of {} each for a total of {}".format(sales_record['person'], sales_record['num_items'], sales_record['price'], sales_record['price'] * sales_record['num_items'])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a recent version of Python (3.6 or newer), replace that line with:

```
sales_statement = f"{sales_record['person']} got {sales_record['num_items']} item(s) at a cost of {sales_record['price']} each for a total of {sales_record['price']*sales_record['num_items']}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is basically because of the quotes.

```
sales_statement = str(sales_record['person']) + " got " + str(sales_record['num_items']) + " item(s) at a cost of " + str(sales_record['price']) + " each for a total of " +  str(sales_record['price']*sales_record['num_items'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes for the full string and single quotes for the dictionary keys so that there is no confusion between them. In Python 3.6 or later. you can use f-strings and enclose the variables in curly braces, by preceding the string with the letter f. Prior to that you would have used the format string method.

```
sales_record = {
    'price': 3.24,
    'num_items': 4,
    'person': 'xyz'
}

sales_statement = f"{sales_record['person']} got {sales_record['num_items']} item(s) " \
                + f"at a cost of {sales_record['price']} each for a total of " \
                + f"{sales_record['price'] * sales_record['num_items']}"

print(sales_statement)
```